# Change div / iframe on scroll?

Tags: css, iframe

```css
.video-embed {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.video-embed iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="video-embeds">
    <div class="video-embed" style="">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/pa4IxrIsr9g" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when user scrolls down of video, I would like this `<div id="video-embeds">`with iframe to jump out to right up corner with different sizes per @media css, and stay there untill user returns up to real video position, than video will again lay up on page...

How to do this? With CSS can?

UPDATE:
I have css I want after scroll.

```
#video-embeds-fixed {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 225px;
    transition-property: opacity, height;
    transition-duration: 366ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.05, 0, 0, 1);
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
    right: 12px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.video-embed-fixed iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now javascript or jquery that changes on scroll #video-embeds to #video-embeds-fixed and .video-embed to .video-embed-fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only css this is impossible, you have to use javascript.
But first change your css fixed id selector to class (#video-embeds-fixed change to .video-embeds-fixed in your css file).

JQuery solution:

```
var video = $('#video-embeds');
var sticky = video.offset().top;
var videoHeight = video.height();
$(window).on('load scroll resize', function() {
    if ((window.pageYOffset) >= (sticky + videoHeight)) {
        video.addClass('video-embeds-fixed');
        video.children('.video-embed').addClass('video-embed-fixed');
    } else {
        video.removeClass('video-embeds-fixed');
        video.children('.video-embed').removeClass('video-embed-fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: It returns to top, when it needs to change. Check here http://lapan.com.ba/denisa-poate-asa-a-fost-sa-fie-in-memoriam-denisa/ It works if I inspect element and scroll.

Comment: It is when page has no much to scroll at bottom, how I can make it stop, or to require more scrolling of video to activate?

Comment: I have check your page again. I see that you have removed css code for .video-embeds-fixed so this is why my code not works. Restore your css classes for fixed element.

Comment: var videoHeight = video.height(); doesnt catch it up.

Comment: Lemme check again as I added style differently to @media sizes

Comment: Yeah, for some reason, it will not catch @media styles in script, and code works but also does that jumping thing again.

Comment: I have take a look at your page - I see that it works properly. Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes! Thank you.